Marketing Cloud - SQL Contatenate columns in alphabetical order
I need to concatenate several columns in an alphabetical order.
Is that possible to be accomplish with Marketing Cloud limited SQL?
Below you can find the sample structure:
SELECT TOP 1
constraintl, constraint2, constraint3, constraint4
FROM OCP_CONTACT_EVENT_REASON_DETAIL_constraints
ORDER BY constraintl, constraint2, constraint3, constraint4 ASC

Output



constraintl
constraint2
constraint3
constraint4




dddd
aaaa
ffff
bbbb




Do you mean concatenate the values of the fields alphabetically?

If you're wanting to sort and concatenate all of the field values, you can do something like this:
CREATE TABLE OCP_CONTACT_EVENT_REASON_DETAIL_constraints (
      field1 varchar(10)
    , constraintl varchar(10)
    , constraint2 varchar(10)
    , constraint3 varchar(10)
    , constraint4 varchar(10)
);
INSERT INTO OCP_CONTACT_EVENT_REASON_DETAIL_constraints
     (field1,constraintl, constraint2, constraint3, constraint4)
VALUES
     ('whee!','dddd','aaaa','ffff','bbbb');
select * from OCP_CONTACT_EVENT_REASON_DETAIL_constraints;

select
field1,
stuff(x.c,1,1,'') as constraints
from OCP_CONTACT_EVENT_REASON_DETAIL_constraints
cross apply (

  select top 4 ',' + rtrim(y.c) from (

    select constraintl as c from OCP_CONTACT_EVENT_REASON_DETAIL_constraints
    union all
    select constraint2 as c from OCP_CONTACT_EVENT_REASON_DETAIL_constraints
    union all
    select constraint3 as c from OCP_CONTACT_EVENT_REASON_DETAIL_constraints
    union all
    select constraint4 as c from OCP_CONTACT_EVENT_REASON_DETAIL_constraints

  ) as y
  order by y.c
  FOR XML PATH('')

) x(c)





field1
constraintl
constraint2
constraint3
constraint4




whee!
dddd
aaaa
ffff
bbbb






field1
constraints




whee!
aaaa,bbbb,dddd,ffff



Try it yourself: dbfiddle

You're lifesaver! :) as I don't need this field1 column, here's what I currently got and it returns null from the Data Extension (however all those columns are not empty). May I ask you to help me assigned your script accordingly?
